# How to make request to webapi in to Sharepoint Online(SPO) c#?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, .net

there is not solid documentation about how to make calls to sharepoint online web api, in MSN documentation it infers that you are developing an add-in for sharepoint, I'm just making a test in c#.

I'm aware of CSOM client nugget but I can't use that. Any example to how use that Web api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a console app, you may take a reference:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TeamifySharePointClassicSite.CsRest
{
    class RestCs
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var siteurl = "https://abc.sharepoint.com";
            var pwd = "iampassword";
            var userName = "admin@abc.onmicrosoft.com";

            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
            pwd.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(s => securePassword.AppendChar(s));

            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

            HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"{siteurl}/_api/web/lists");
            endpointRequest.Credentials = credentials;
            endpointRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
            endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
           
            HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader streamR = new StreamReader(endpointResponse.GetResponseStream());

            Console.WriteLine(streamR.ReadToEnd());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use other authentication methods such as OAuth:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#authenticationmanager-sample-class
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints#reading-data-with-the-sharepoint-rest-interface

BR

Comment: i read about the header "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED" when i add it an exception occurs like my user does not exists and it does, but if i remove that a 403(forbidden) error is raise.

Comment: Check if Legacy Authentication is disabled for tenant. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/sharepoint-online-authentication-in-powershell-for-csom-when/ba-p/510114

Comment: i think this is a weird issue because LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled  is set to True, but now an error, Cannot contact web site 'https://trainee4.sharepoint.com/' or the web site does not support SharePoint Online credentials. The response status code is 'Unauthorized'. but as i said it gives me all that when the header its set to "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", if i ignore that an 403 error is raise. but I'm using a trial version i think that could be the main issue, but i wanted to tested.